# General questions about #! hashbang urls and am I using them correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm in the process of writing a website that includes a reasonably large gallery. First page of the gallery the user will be displayed a bunch of thumbnail images with a url of: website.com/gallery.php

When they click a thumbnail image, if javaScript is turned off it will follow the url in the href and go to a page called gallery.php?img=67. If javaScript is turned on the href click will not execute, instead it will perform an ajax request to display the larger image and some text about it. The url changes to gallery.php#!img=67. The back button will take you back to the thumbnails, pressing f5 will keep the big image displayed with the text. If someone copies the address with the #! and sends it to someone they will get the same image displayed (assuming the receiver has javaScript turned on).

My question is, have I sorted this out correctly for google to index the individual gallery pages? Will google index them twice, once with the ?img=67 and once with the #! and if so is that a bad thing? I'm using javaScript/Ajax to preload the larger images once the thumbnail page is loaded for speed. I've read a lot of backlash against using hasbang ajaxy things recently and wondering if you think can justify using it here?

Comment: Google ignores the hash and everything after it.

Comment: Not according to this http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html - I should add I've set the server up to respond to the crawler as talk about in that link

Comment: As you are using the standard URL in the HREF and only creating the #!URL with javascript (the right way to do it IMO), google won't see your #!URLs anyway and will just index the standard version.

Comment: Yes I'm using <a href="gallery.php?img=67" onclick="ajaxyMagic();return false;"> So a web browser with javascript turned on will not follow the href, but a browser with no javaScript support will just follow the href. Ah ok I see, google wont index the page twice then, but deep links from google will go to the non javascript version of the site. Doesn't seem to be anyway to do this without trade-offs of some description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google will follow your links and index the `?img=67` pages, and will not index your `#!` pages, because it can't see those links. You can tell Google about those links by doing the following:

1. Add `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to the `<head>` of your document, and
2. Handle requests for `/?_escaped_fragment_=` by returning an "HTML Snapshot" of your page that has all your `#!` links in the `<A>` tags.

Also, to make the most of this feature, you should also handle requests for `/?_escaped_fragment_=img=67` by returning an HTML snapshot page with the big image displayed. Remember, GoogleBot doesn't execute Javascript. Using the `#!` URL tells Google to retrieve an alternate version of the page (A version where `#!` has been replaced with `?_escaped_fragment_=`) that **should render without Javascript**.

Comment: I haven't put #! links in the href attribute though, they're in the onClick event, so even with the added meta tag google still wont find the #! links will it?

Comment: No, Google will ignore the onClick code, just like it ignores any other JavaScript. They key is that when Google sees the `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` tag, it will retrieve a different version of the page, with a `?_escaped_fragment_=` variable. If you respond to that request with a page full of links with `#!` in the `href`, Google will see and index them.

Comment: But remember that having Google index the `#!` links is similarly useless unless you properly respond to the `?_escaped_fragment_=img=67` requests. Your server should respond with a page that has the big image displayed, just like regular users see, except that page should render **without JavaScript**.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for that! Gee it's a lot of effort to use the #! correctly even if you can justify using it. Starting to see why there is so much backlash against it.

Comment: Yeah, it would probably make life easier for a lot of us if Google's crawler just executed all of our JavaScript and indexed the resulting DOM. But that might be asking too much. :)

Answer (score 1):

THe use of `#!` tags in URLs are in the news recently, with updates to a well known blog.

http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs has a good description of what they are best used for - and when they can be bad.  I think your use in a gallery is quite valid.

In short, a URL like http://lifehacker.com/#!5753509/hello-world... is rewritten by Google, and other compatible web-spiders as http://lifehacker.com/?_escaped_fragment_=5753509/hello-world...

Google may index them twice, but you can also use the [canonical](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) meta-tag to ensure it knows what the 'official' copy is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the canonical meta tag, should be a good way of preventing google from deep linking to the non javaScript version of the site.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no scenario in which a URL with an _escaped_fragmented_ portion would be visible to a user.  Google uses #! in the search results, and they instruct developers to use it as well in the links on the page.  Only the Googlebot and the server are ever using _escaped_fragment_

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution (as suggested in http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) is to use regular links and translate them to #! in the OnClick() event. This ensures that the site displays regular links and not the shitty #!.

It does mean extra work for the server though, since the server needs  to support both versions (the Ajax version and the regular version),  but I think it worth it.These #! are so ugly..